# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python, lista

Estoy intentando resolver un ejercicio en el cual solo tengo que sumar los numeros que aparecen en una cadena. Lo hice de esta forma:

```
cadena = "abc123def123ghi321"
lista = []
suma = 0

for letras in cadena:
    if letras.isnumeric():
        lista.append(letras)
    else:
        pass

lista_numerica = "".join(lista)

print(sum(lista))
```

El problema es el error que me aparece por la última linea:
***"TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'"***
¿Que estoy planteando mal? No logro entenderlo.
Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que no estas sumando un array de números sino un array con muchas cadenas o caracteres, por más que sea uno solo por elemento.

Si luego de hacer el recorrido imprimes la variable lista:

```
.....

for letras in cadena:
    if letras.isnumeric():
        lista.append(letras)

print(lista)
```

Verás en la consola:

> ['1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3', '3', '2', '1']

Debes transformar el caracter a número antes de meterlo en el array:

```
for letras in cadena:
    if letras.isnumeric():
        lista.append(int(letras))
    else:
        pass
    
print(lista)

print(sum(lista))
```

Nota el uso de la función **int()** dentro de **append**

Como nota aparte, no necesitas ese **else pass**. Simplemente no coloques nada y se entiende que si no se da la condición pues no se ejecuta nada.

```
for letras in cadena:
    if letras.isnumeric():
        lista.append(int(letras))
    
print(lista)

print(sum(lista))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Cuando haces `lista.append(letras)`, estas agregando el valor como texto (str), para solucionar el problema, llama al constructor de números enteros al añadir el elemento a la lista.

```
cadena = "abc123def123ghi321"
lista = []
suma = 0

for letras in cadena:
    if letras.isnumeric():
        lista.append(int(letras))
    else:
        pass

print(sum(lista))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Una manera de hacerlo mediante comprensión de listas:

```
cadena = "abc123def123ghi321"

print(sum([int(n) for n in cadena if n.isdigit()]))
```

Con esto devuelve `18`